# Testing string equality issue

Tags: c

Haven't programmed in C in a while, so I'm surely missing something here but I can't figure out what it is.

I have two strings, as shown below:

```
char toMatch[] = "--exit--";
char entry[1024];
```

Through this program, I have a while loop that accepts user input to modify the string `entry` throughout the program. I would like to exit this while loop when `entry` equals `toMatch`.

I thought this was easy to do with the `strcmp` function, but it's not working for some reason. Originally I had this:

```
while(strcmp(entry, toMatch) != 0) {
    // accept user input here to modify entry
}
```

However, this didn't work. So I added one line of code to clear the contents of `entry` before accepting user input again:

```
while(strcmp(entry, toMatch) != 0) {
    memset(entry, 0, sizeof(entry));
    // accept user input here to modify entry
}
```

This doesn't work either. I need to have `entry` be this long, because the entry of the user can be any length smaller than this. I have no idea why `strcmp()` is not working, so I think I'm missing something that should be obvious.

Comment: Show us the piece of code that ask you for the string input

Comment: You're aware that ==0 is equality, and <0 or >0 are inequality, right? Outside of that, have you printed out the values of the two strings -- preferably with a character before and after them, such as '"', to make spaces visible -- to confirm that you really are comparing what you think you're comparing?

Comment: The user input probably ends with a newline.  Try setting tomatch to "--exit--\n".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `strcmp()` is easy enough if you always write the comparison explicitly with zero:

- `strcmp(a, b) == 0` for equality
- `strcmp(a, b) != 0` for inequality
- `strcmp(a, b) >= 0` for `a` sorts equal to or after `b`
- `strcmp(a, b) >  0` for `a` sorts after `b`
- `strcmp(a, b) <= 0` for `a` sorts equal to or before `b`
- `strcmp(a, b) <  0` for `a` sorts before `b`

If you're having problems matching `"--exit--"` against your input, did you strip leading blanks, trailing blanks, trailing newline (especially the latter if you read the input with `fgets()`).  What does this show:

```
printf("[[%s]]\n", entry);
```

The square brackets show you where the program thinks the ends of the string are.

Comment: This was exactly the issue. I had trailing blanks, which was causing the issue. Thank you!