# How to properly use strcmp in a function

Tags: c++, string, pointers, compare, strcmp

I'm having a hard time understanding how to use strcmp. It seems like changes I make to the strings being sent to the equals() function don't affect the outcome of Tests 1a - 1d. What is the purpose of the exclamation points in front of the function calls? The purpose of this program is to compare two strings which will display "correct" if the strings are the same length and same case. The follwoing code was provided by my professor. I can only change what is inside the equal() function and the function prototype.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstring>
    #include <cctype>

    using std::cin;
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

bool equals(const char*, const char*);

int main()
   {

   // Tests 1a - 1d: Test the equals() function
   cout << "Test 1a: ";
   if (equals("catapult", "catapult"))
      cout << "correct\n";
   else
      cout << "incorrect\n";

   cout << "Test 1b: ";
   if (!equals("catapult", "catamaran"))
      cout << "correct\n";
   else
      cout << "incorrect\n";

   cout << "Test 1c: ";
   if (!equals("cat", "catamaran"))
      cout << "correct\n";
   else
      cout << "incorrect\n";

   cout << "Test 1d: ";
   if (!equals("catapult", "cat"))
      cout << "correct\n";
   else
      cout << "incorrect\n";

   cout << endl;
return 0;
}

bool equals (const char* str1, const char* str2)
{
    if (strcmp(str1, str2) == 0)
        return true;

    return false;

}
```

Comment: This is how you properly use `strcmp` in c++: step 1: replace every occurrence of `char const*` with `std::string`, step 2: replace every occurrence of `strcmp` with `==`.

Comment: `!` is the logical-not operator, which changes a following `false` to `true`, or `true` to `false`.  So `!true` `==` `false`, and `!false` `==` `true`.  `!equals(x, y)` means "not (equals(x, y))" or - paraphrasing in English - "x is not equal to y".

Comment: "if the strings are the same length and same case" - this is not what `strcmp` tests... to compare equal they must be the same length and every character must match exactly... just being the same upper- or lower-case is not enough.

Comment: Running your program - they all print "correct" [(tested on ideone.com here)](http://ideone.com/L9ATyh)... that's because each test is designed to use `equals` or `!equals` according to the known equality or inequality of the arguments.

Comment: I should have worded this a bit better. I know that "!" is negation. I just don't understand why it is there in this specific case. Those tests were made by my professor. The function as well as what is past to it were also already provided. I'm only providing the code inside the function. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It isn't strictly a duplicate since it is for C, not C++, but the question [Testing string equality issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691339/testing-string-equality-issue/) has an answer that makes using `strcmp()` pretty easy.  Of course, since I wrote the answer, I'm biassed, but I think it does make life easier.

Answer (score 0):

The exclamation point, when used as a unary prefix operator, is the *logical not* (or negation) operator.

So

```
if (!equals("catapult", "catamaran"))
```

should be read as if the negation of `equals("catapult","catamaran")` is true,
in other words if `equals("catapult","catamaran")` is false.

<sup>Notice that the negation operator `!` has *lower precedence* than function call. So your `!equals("catapult","catamaran")` has the same meaning as `!(equals("catapult","catamaran"))`</sup>

BTW, you should learn about [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) if you want to code in genuine C++. And you should read the documentation of [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) and see also [strcasecmp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcasecmp.html)

At last, you should compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g`) and use the debugger (`gdb`) to run your program step by step.

Comment: I should have worded this a bit better. I know that "!" is negation. I just don't understand why it is there in this specific case. Those tests were made by my professor. The function as well as what is past to it were also already provided. I'm only providing the code inside the function. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Because your professor does not expect `"cat"` to be the "same" as  `"catamaran"` and he is right.

Comment: Are you saying that the exclamations are pseudocode? It just doesn't make sense to  me to make a function that compares strings when the returned value will just be flipped from the negation.

Comment: It does has sense. Defining a `not_equal` function would be useless once you got `equal` function. But please run your example step by step in a debugger to understand more.